# znapzend not taking snapshots after the initial set up

Tags: znapzend

I installed znapzend on unraid and did the initial configuration. My daemon is running but `zfs list -t snapshot` shows `no datasets available`

```
*** backup plan: citadel ***
         enabled = on
         mbuffer = off
    mbuffer_size = 1G
   post_znap_cmd = off
    pre_znap_cmd = off
       recursive = on
             src = citadel
        src_plan = 7days=>1hour,30days=>4hours,90days=>1day
        tsformat = %Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S
      zend_delay = 0

NOTE: if you have modified your configuration, send a HUP signal
(pkill -HUP znapzend) to your znapzend daemon for it to notice the change.
```

I created the backup plan like this `znapzendzetup create --recursive SRC '7d=>1h,30d=>4h,90d=>1d' citadel`

debug shows the below

```
root@UnRAID:~# znapzend --noaction --debug
=== getDataSetProperties():
        recurse=$VAR1 = 1;

        inherit=$VAR1 = 0;

        DS=$VAR1 = [
          undef
        ];

        lowmemRecurse=0
=== getDataSetProperties(): Is array...
=== getDataSetProperties(): skip array context: value(s) inside undef...
=== getDataSetProperties(): List all local datasets on the system...
# zfs list -H -o name -t filesystem,volume
=== getDataSetProperties(): Looking under 'citadel' with zfsGetType='0', '0' recursion mode and '0' inheritance mode
# zfs get -H -s local -o name,property,value,source all citadel
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'tsformat' == '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'mbuffer' == 'off' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'mbuffer_size' == '1G' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'enabled' == 'on' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'pre_znap_cmd' == 'off' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'zend_delay' == '0' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'post_znap_cmd' == 'off' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'src_plan' == '7days=>1hours,30days=>4hours,90days=>1days' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): FOUND: 'citadel' => 'recursive' == 'on' (source: 'local')
=== getDataSetProperties(): SAVE LAST: 'citadel'
=== getDataSetProperties(): Looking under 'citadel/Documents' with zfsGetType='0', '0' recursion mode and '0' inheritance mode
# zfs get -H -s local -o name,property,value,source all citadel/Documents
=== getDataSetProperties(): Looking under 'citadel/Media' with zfsGetType='0', '0' recursion mode and '0' inheritance mode
# zfs get -H -s local -o name,property,value,source all citadel/Media
=== getDataSetProperties(): Looking under 'citadel/TimeMachine' with zfsGetType='0', '0' recursion mode and '0' inheritance mode
# zfs get -H -s local -o name,property,value,source all citadel/TimeMachine
=== getDataSetProperties(): Looking under 'citadel/Torrent_Downloads' with zfsGetType='0', '0' recursion mode and '0' inheritance mode
# zfs get -H -s local -o name,property,value,source all citadel/Torrent_Downloads
=== getDataSetProperties(): Looking under 'citadel/software' with zfsGetType='0', '0' recursion mode and '0' inheritance mode
# zfs get -H -s local -o name,property,value,source all citadel/software
=== getDataSetProperties(): Looking under 'citadel/veeam-backup' with zfsGetType='0', '0' recursion mode and '0' inheritance mode
# zfs get -H -s local -o name,property,value,source all citadel/veeam-backup
=== getDataSetProperties():
        Collected: $VAR1 = {
          'enabled' => 'on',
          'recursive' => 'on',
          'mbuffer' => 'off',
          'src' => 'citadel',
          'post_znap_cmd' => 'off',
          'zend_delay' => '0',
          'tsformat' => '%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S',
          'src_plan' => '7days=>1hours,30days=>4hours,90days=>1days',
          'mbuffer_size' => '1G',
          'pre_znap_cmd' => 'off'
        };

# zfs list -H -o name -t filesystem,volume citadel
=== getBackupSet() : got 1 dataset(s) with a local backup plan
=== getBackupSet() : got 1 enabled-only dataset(s) with a local backup plan
```

This is the first time I am using it and I am certain I am doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spoke too soon guys. It is working. I had to wait till the new hour started